# Use put_internal to upload file using python eve

Tags: python, eve

I want to store media files on certain mongo documents. 
I was thinking of using eve's put_internal method call to update the document. 
How would I use the payload param to provide the file as payload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to provide the file value as a [FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) object. So suppose your media field is called `media`, a hypothetical payload would look like:

```
{'media': <FileStorage: u'example.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, ...}
```

In order to achieve that you would do something like:

```
from werkzeug import FileStorage

f = open('example.jpg','r')    
fs = FileStorage(f)

payload['media'] = fs
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola. That is what i ended up doing

Comment: Is there support for having mutiple grid collection with different prefixes, for instance I want to not call my grid prefix not 'fs' but something else ?